# Does calling updateValueAndValidity() on a FormControl trigger Angular's change detection

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-changedetection

When calling `updateValueAndValidity()` on a Angular FormControl does this trigger Angular change detection for the component?

for example:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.email.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.password.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Will this trigger change detection twice?

Is it more efficient to call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` once?

Does this depend on what I set the `emitEvent` argument to?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity this should answer you question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing I used the following code to change two different FormControl values outside of Angular's change detection.

```js
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  this.email.setValue('test@email');
  this.password.setValue('test-password');
});
```

Using the ngDoCheck Lifecycle hook, I was able to count how many times change detection was run.

```js
ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('checking for ', ++this.timesChecked);
}
```

Then I ran `updateValueAndValidity()` twice back within the zone and discovered that Angular change detection was only triggered once. Even when I set `{onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false}` it still only triggered it once.

In conclusion it appears that if you need to trigger change detection for all FormControls its sufficient to either call `updateValueAndValidity()` on one form control or to call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` once since both end up triggering a full change detection cycle.